# Reading WebVTT files in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, webvtt, vtt

Does anyone have experience with reading WebVTT (.vtt) files using PHP?

I'm developing an application in CakePHP where I need to read through a bunch of vtt files and get the start time and associated text.

So as an example of the file:

```
00:00.999 --> 00:04.999
sentence one

00:04.999 --> 00:07.999
sentence two

00:07.999 --> 00:10.999
third sentence
with a line break

00:10.999 --> 00:14.999
a fourth sentence
on three
lines
```

I need to be able to extract something like this:

```
00:00.999 sentence one
00:04.999 sentence two
00:07.999 third sentence with a line break
00:10.999 a fourth sentence on three lines
```

Note that there can be line breaks so there's no set number of lines between each timestamp.

My plan was to search for "-->" which is a common string between each timestamp. Does anyone have any ideas how best to achieve this?

Comment: You'll probably receive better answers if you'd elaborate the specific problem you are facing a little more. The best way? There are hundreds of different ways, what have you tried so far? How about `strpos()`? If you need something basic to get started, itereate over all lines, use `strpos()` to check for `-->`, parse the line using `preg_match()`, read all following lines into a string until you reach an empty line, repeat until reaching EOF. For more information on parsing WebVTT files see [**the Parsing section of the WebVTT specs**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webvtt/#parsing).

Comment: Well, the specific problem is I'm looking for the best way to achieve the output I've given in the example. So elaborating on how I may do this using your suggestions (strpos and preg_match) is really the information I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

To parse file you can use library like this:

```
$subtitles = Subtitles::loadFromFile('subtitles.vtt');
$blocks = $subtitles->getInternalFormat(); // array

foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    echo $block['start'];
    echo ' ';
    foreach ($block['lines'] as $line) {
        echo $line . ' ';
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

It will also get text from files containing styles and other small errors.

https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles

Answer (score 1):

This seems to achieve what I need, i.e. outputs the Start Time and any subsequent lines of text. The files I'm using are fairly small so using PHP's file() function to read everything into an array seems ok; not sure this would work well on large files though.

```
    $file = 'test.vtt'; 
    $file_as_array = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    foreach ($file_as_array as $f) {    

        // Find lines containing "-->"  
        $start_time = false;
        if (preg_match("/^(\d{2}:[\d\.]+) --> \d{2}:[\d\.]+$/", $f, $match)) {              
            $start_time = explode('-->', $f);
            $start_time = $start_time[0];
            echo '<br>';
            echo $start_time;
        }

        // It's a line of the file that doesn't include a timestamp, so it's caption text. Ignore header of file which includes the word 'WEBVTT'
        if (!$start_time && (!strpos($f, 'WEBVTT')) ) {             
            echo ' ' . $f . ' ';
        }   

    }       
}
```

Comment: I had to adjust the Regex to account for hh:mm:ss, but other that it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<?PHP

function send_reformatted($vtt_file){
 // Add these headers to ease saving the output as text file
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$vtt_file.'.txt"');

    $f = fopen($vtt_file, "r");
    $line_new = "";

    while($line = fgets($f)){
        if (preg_match("/^(\d{2}:[\d\.]+) --> \d{2}:[\d\.]+$/", $line, $match)) {
            if($line_new) echo $line_new."\n";
            $line_new = $match[1];
        } else{
            $line = trim($line);
            if($line) $line_new .= " $line";
        }
    }

    echo $line_new."\n";
    fclose($f);
}


send_reformatted("test.vtt");

?>
```

Comment: That just seems to output the entire file? If you copied the example I gave into a file called test.vtt and then ran send_reformatted("test.vtt") it would just output the file as supplied.

Comment: I have tested this before I posted the code above and it worked well for me. I have to check why it won't work for you. I am on ubuntu. What is your operating system?

Comment: Running it on a CentOS server under Apache, PHP 5.3. I've actually come up with something which is almost working for my needs so will post it in full once it's done. The preg_match in your reply above was very useful and have used that in my solution. Thanks.